# How can i use hover property with two classes

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two css classes

```
    .circle-btn{
    }
    .circle-btn-medium{
    }
```

Hhowever both classes having their own properties. But at hover property I want to use same background color for both.

One solution i found is what to use hover property seperatly as follows

```
.circle-btn:hover
{
    background-color:#39C11E;
}
.circle-btn-medium:hover
{
    background-color:#39C11E;
}
```

So instead of using hover property separately is it possible to use this property with different classes at same time so I can optimize my coding?

Comment: Yes, you can use a comma to seperate them, `.someclass:hover, .anotherclass:hover { /* styles here */ }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can minimize it by joining the 2 class in to one ..

```
.circle-btn:hover , 
.circle-btn-medium:hover {
    background-color: #39c11E;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one or two classes in your html. So `-medium` will be modifier, which responce only for size.

For example:

css:

```
.circle-btn{
}
.circle-btn-medium{
}
.circle-btn:hover
{
     background-color:#39C11E;
}
```

html:

```
 <!-- common circle-btn -->
 <button class="circle-btn">circle button</button>

 <!-- medium circle-btn -->
 <button class="circle-btn circle-btn-medium">circle medium button</button>
```

By the way, this is bootstrap way. Just look, for example, to their [buttons sizes modifiers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes).